# Mysql Query get Unbooked date for hotels booking room

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this,

```
Mst_Booking
    room_id int(11),
    order_id int(11),
    start datettime,
    end datetime
```

I can get specific date that booked by this query

`select * from Mst_Booking etc..,`

the result

```
1   1   2017-01-01  2017-01-08
1   1   2017-01-11  2017-01-12
```

but I cannot get the data where have not listed in there
like this

"The Unbooked/ available date"

```
room_id     start         end
1           2017-01-09    2017-01-10
1           2017-01-13    2017-01-31
```

please help me should I create more table to marking the unbooked? or there is query to retrieve data as per my requirement?

Comment: you should have a flag column in your table .....that denotes if booked then  1 else 0 that will be easy to fetch booked and not booked hotel rooms detail

Comment: You can try approaching your problem from a different way.  The likely use case is a user searching for availabilities in a given range.  You can query your table to find possible matches.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369477/mysql-to-check-room-availability-in-a-hotel-for-a-particular-date-and-time-durat?rq=1

Comment: @Ankit Agrawal: the data only 
room_id     id_order   start         end
1           1          2017-01-01  2017-01-08
1           1          2017-01-11  2017-01-12

and this data is not exist in table
room_id     start         end
1           2017-01-09    2017-01-10
1           2017-01-13    2017-01-31
are flag column can generate the UnExist data like above with query? how the logic?

Comment: Thx all, ihace a logic inspire by all of u to solved this,
im create new table with column like this
room_id: generate this value for every room we have (flag for room used)
Thedate: generate this value automatically every month or as we need
booked: generate default 0 for unbooked, but iwant to know from the expert, are this still efficience, according to data that will be grown by time, thx

Comment: What's your primary key?

Answer (score 0):

If the view doesn't bother you, we can list the 'Un-booked' dates with respect to each room_id one below the other>>

Your table:

```
mysql> select * from mst_booking;

+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| room_id | order_id | start_date          | end_date            |
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 |        1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017-01-08 00:00:00 |
|       1 |        2 | 2017-01-11 00:00:00 | 2017-01-12 00:00:00 |
|       1 |        3 | 2017-01-17 00:00:00 | 2017-01-21 00:00:00 |
|       1 |        4 | 2017-01-25 00:00:00 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00 |
|       2 |        5 | 2017-01-17 00:00:00 | 2017-01-21 00:00:00 |
|       2 |        6 | 2017-01-25 00:00:00 | 2017-01-27 00:00:00 |
|       3 |        7 | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 | 2017-01-19 00:00:00 |
|       3 |        8 | 2017-01-25 00:00:00 | 2017-01-29 00:00:00 |    
+---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

To list out the 'Un-booked' dates:

```
select room_id, adddate(end_date,1) as date from mst_booking where   
room_id=1 UNION select room_id,subdate(start_date,1) as date from 
mst_booking where start_date not in (select min(start_date) from 
mst_booking where room_id=1) and room_id=1 order by date;
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| room_id | date                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2017-01-09 00:00:00 |
|       1 | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 |
|       1 | 2017-01-13 00:00:00 |
|       1 | 2017-01-16 00:00:00 |
|       1 | 2017-01-22 00:00:00 |
|       1 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |
|       1 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

You can see that the 'un-booked / available' date-range are listed one below other.

For room_id=2:

```
select room_id, adddate(end_date,1) as date from mst_booking where  
room_id=2 UNION select room_id,subdate(start_date,1) as date from  
mst_booking where start_date not in (select min(start_date) from 
mst_booking where room_id=2) and room_id=2 order by date;
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| room_id | date                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       2 | 2017-01-22 00:00:00 |
|       2 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |
|       2 | 2017-01-28 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

For room_id=3:

```
select room_id, adddate(end_date,1) as date from mst_booking where     
room_id=3 UNION select room_id,subdate(start_date,1) as date from  
mst_booking where start_date not in (select min(start_date) from 
mst_booking where room_id=3) and room_id=3 order by date;
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| room_id | date                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       3 | 2017-01-20 00:00:00 |
|       3 | 2017-01-24 00:00:00 |
|       3 | 2017-01-30 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```